# Testlink 1.9.12 - first install : interface is empty without warning

Tags: testlink

I just installed Testlink1.9.12 on Windows with XAMPP.
I have no warning during the check.

But when I log in with my admin account I access to the testlink interface but it is empty.

It seems like mainpage does not load php page for each modules (User management/Requirements/Specifications/Execution...)

Can someone give me help to solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe faster to ask on the Testlink installation forums: http://forum.testlink.org/viewforum.php?f=1&sid=a9ce49c695982a900c8673166ebe386d

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into the error logs. You can find them in the path definied in `config.inc.php` of testlink. The variable is called `$tlCfg->log_path`. Default is `/var/testlink/logs` for Unix but you can change it whatever you want, even on win.

Than you will find more information about it in the log. For me it was that `cURL` was not activated for the issue tracker to work with